# How nasal hairs filter particles of micron size?

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy

[This book says:](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5yxEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=The%20larger%20particles%20(%3E%2010%20%CE%BCm%20diameter)%20are%20indu%20khurana&source=bl&ots=Dq7jh2IIMn&sig=TJ8k6i_hmfRPNWp3SrCUanZQQCc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdm7X-qbXSAhUJHZQKHfEjBzEQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The larger particles (> 10 μm diameter) are filtered by hair in the nostrils

If we see the anatomy of nasal hairs and its density in the nostrils then it seems that its impossible for such a structure to filter particles in micrometers, So how does the nasal hairs filter them?

Comment: That's not strictly true. Particulate matter of less than 10μm in diameter (expressed as PM˘10) reach lower airways, and 10μm diameter reaches the bronchial tree, Hair disturbs airflow allowing for deposition, is moist and can catch small particles; mucus on surface epithelium and hair can as well. But it's a combination of a lot of mechanisms that keep out larger particles. Shape of the particle also matters. But pollen of 20μm has been found in lung periphery.